# Android: How can I read the value of a custom GATT characteristic?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I am trying to read the data of a custom characteristic from a device that runs Mynewt.

Until the point that I discover all the services everything works fine.

Here is the part of my code.

```
@Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
        if (status == 0){
            List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
            peripheralTextView.append("onServicesDiscovered " + services.toString() + "\n\n");
            readCustomCharacteristic();
        }
    }

    public void readCustomCharacteristic() {
        if (btAdapter == null || mGatt == null) {
            peripheralTextView.append("BluetoothAdapter not initialized \n");
            return;
        }
    /*check if the service is available on the device*/
        BluetoothGattService mCustomService = mGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("59462F12-9543-9999-12C8-58B459A2712D"));
        if(mCustomService == null){
            peripheralTextView.append("Custom BLE Service not found \n");
            return;
        }
    /*get the read characteristic from the service*/
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic mReadCharacteristic = mCustomService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("5C3A659E-897E-45E1-B016-007107C96DF6"));
        mGatt.readCharacteristic(mReadCharacteristic);

        if(mReadCharacteristic == null){
            peripheralTextView.append("Failed to read characteristic \n");
        }
        else {
            peripheralTextView.append("Characteristic " + mGatt.getService(serviceUUID).getCharacteristic(characteristicUUID).toString() + "\n");
        }
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        peripheralTextView.append("The characteristic UUID is : " + characteristic.getUuid());
        peripheralTextView.append("The value is : " + characteristic.getStringValue(0));
    }
```

I have also tried other methods for reading the data such as valueOf, getValue etc.

With some of these methods I am getting as an answer null and with some others the whole line is not even print on my screen.

The out put on my mobile screen is this one
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Os3DA.png)

I always run my app on my phone: Samsung Galaxy A5 (2016)

Is there any other way/method to read the data from the characteristic or do I miss something?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
[Screenshot for status parameter behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Os3DA.png)  with the use of getValue method

Comment: If you use getValue() in the onCharacteristicRead callback, does that return null or an array of length 0?

Comment: It returns null. After a very careful step-by-step debugging process, I saw that the mValue of the characteristic is null.

Comment: What's the value of the status parameter?

Comment: @Emil Status value is 137

Comment: @Emil Actually I put to print status variable on my mobile screen. I randomly noticed that if I call readCharacteristic second time or maybe third (with the use of a button that calls the readCharacteristic ) the status at some point turns to be 0, which in the documentation says GATT_SUCCESS. Status: 137 -> 7 -> 0 or 137 -> 0. I edit my post with a screenshot .... Any idea?

Comment: Most likely this is an ATT error code returned from your peripheral. Bluetooth Core specification 5.0, Vol 3, Part F, section 3.4.1.1 describes the error codes. In this case 137 (0x89) is defined as "Application Error", which is application-dependent what that means. Error 7 means "Invalid Offset" which is usually returned if the peripheral returns a Long Characteristic that is longer than the maximum allowed by the spec (512 bytes). You need to fix the issue at the peripheral side.

Comment: @Emil Finally, I had some free time to check out what you said. Now it works great. Thanks a lot!